# Is there an equivalent to rsync --archive --files-from= on Windows?

Tags: windows, rsync, access-control-list

I would like to copy selected paths from source to destination directory including all metadata and ACLs. Is it possible using Windows CLI?

`robocopy src dst /E /COPY:DATSO /SECFIX /TIMFIX /sl /TS /FP` is close, but its options to filter paths are very limited. It's possible to provide only filenames with wildcards but not full paths. I would like something like: `rsync --archive --files-from=FILE` where FILE contains paths relative to `src`:

```
path/to/one/file
path/to/another/file
```

Answer (score 0):

As a work around, you can create a bat file including the full paths from the source and the destination. Also I use to use this attibs while using robocpy /e /s /eta /r:3

/eta | will give you the estimated time for each file copy
/r:3 | will try 3 times the copy after the third fail, will skip the file

I hope this can help you in some way